# Ruby issue while configuring sensu checks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devops, sensu

I have sensu server and sensu-client Installed on one machine (centos) and installed the the plugins through gem.

Everything was good when I run the `check_ping.rb` from the command line, but When I configure the same check in `/etc/sensu/conf.d/` and check in the UI I am getting this ruby issue;

```
gem install sensu-plugins-network-checks
```

I have ruby installed of 1.9.3 version

and configured `EMBEDDED_RUBY=true`

when I check the UI the below is the error I am facing

```
/opt/sensu/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- net/ping (LoadError)
from /opt/sensu/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/sensu-plugins-network-checks-0.2.4/bin/check-ping.rb:31:in `<main>'
Sensu::Plugin::CLI: ["Not implemented! You should override Sensu::Plugin::CLI#run."]
```

Can someone help with this?

Answer (score 0):

It is a common issue that Gems get installed but not to the embedded ruby which you are using.
what you want to do is `/opt/sensu/embedded/bin/gem install net/ping`
so it is in the right place.

The alternative option for this would be to edit `/etc/default/sensu` file and change embedded ruby to `false` then it would use your regular ruby and the corresponding gems.